# How can i resolve the BadRequest

Tags: azure-web-app-service, timeoutexception

I created a Logic App. In the logic app we are Calling Our Own API Called App Service(F1-Free).We are on a free service plan.

- My Client Actually We intended for Few number of Hits at a time. But My Client Is Dumping Bulk Data At a Time. With this we are facing the Time Out limt Issue.
  What is the solution for this Issue.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E89tZ.jpg).

BadRequest. Http request failed: the server did not respond within the timeout limit. Please see logic app limits at https://aka.ms/logic-apps-limits-and-config#http-limits

Comment: 1. Ask client not to dump the large data. 2. Implement request throttling 3. Buy paid plan with larger quota.

Comment: You're perhaps getting what you paid for.. Have you worked out the cost of upgrading? If it turns out to be a few dollars it'll be far cheaper than doing any work to fix the problem; never confuse "cost" with "value"

Answer (score 0):

In Logic App HTTP request Max time out is 120 Sec. So try maintaining the HTTP request below 120 sec to avoid Bad request failure.

[image]

Here is the [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-limits-and-config?tabs=azure-portal) for complete details about timeout limits in logic app.